# How can I attach a newly added paragraph to existing records?

Tags: 8, paragraphs

While editing a form, I needed to delete some fields and add a new paragraph.
The issue here is, the newly added paragraph is not initialized in the edit form and that makes sense because the old data don't have that field so I have to initialize it manually by clicking on "Add Paragraph", then Save otherwise I won't be able to access it programmatically, but I have hundreds of users and I can't do that.

How can I add a paragraph to existing records?

I'm unable to use Drush on this server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add newly created paragraphs (without saving them) to the node field:

```
$node->field_paragraph[] = Paragraph::create([
  'type' => 'paragraph_type',
  'field_foo' => 'bar',
]);
```

and save them later together with the node:

```
$node->save();
```

Comment: I think the question is regarding how to do so in bulk and without Drush. So I think we need also to add at a minimum an entity query and an update hook.

Comment: Yes ! it's working fine ! You saved me a lot of hours.
Thank you

Comment: @cilefen I think you are right! How to do that?

Comment: I am certain there are answers on this forum for that and all over the Internet. Example: https://www.thirdandgrove.com/insights/using-batch-api-and-hookupdaten-drupal-8/. If there are very many of these you may have to enqueue them, but that's only if the update is too time-consuming.

Comment: The link you provided was exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot.